# My GUI pops up when I press "M" while typing in chat

Tags: lua, roblox

Ok so I have a problem. I got a Webhook report gui and script which opens by pressing the M key. But when I press M while typing it opens the GUI. How can I solve this? It works perfectly just that "M" key opening the GUI even though I am typing.

```
local key = Enum.KeyCode.M -- Change the key if you want.
local gui = script.Parent.main -- Main frame
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer -- get local player
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService") -- get service

gui:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.382, 0, 1.229, 0))

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(Input)
    if Input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Keyboard and Input.KeyCode == key then --User pressed key
        if gui.Position == UDim2.new(0.382, 0, 0.229, 0) then --If open
            gui:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.382, 0, 1.229, 0)) --Close UI
        else --Is closed
            gui:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.382, 0, 0.229, 0)) --Open UI

        end
    end
end)


local sendbtn = script.Parent.main.send --- send button
local message = script.Parent.main.messageinput -- message box
local repstorage = game:WaitForChild("ReplicatedStorage")
local send = repstorage.reportevents.send
local sendcheck = false -- stop spam of the send button
local cooldowntxt = script.Parent.main.cooldown
cooldowntxt.Visible = false
---- DISCORD WEBHOOK CONFIG IS IN SERVERSCRIPTSERVICE (report)

sendbtn.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if sendcheck == false then -- checks if it was sent recently
        sendcheck = true
        send:FireServer(message.Text, sendcheck) -- sends it to server from client (serverscriptservice)
        sendbtn.Text = "Sent!" -- Customize if you want
        wait(0.7)-- Customize if you want
        sendbtn.Text = "A staff member will be with you soon!"-- Customize if you want
        wait(1.5)-- Customize if you want
        sendbtn.Text = "Send"-- Customize if you want
        cooldowntxt.Visible = true
        wait(70)-- Customize if you want
        sendcheck = false
        cooldowntxt.Visible = false
    end
end)

print("Config loaded")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [UserInputService.InputBegan signal](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/UserInputService/InputBegan) has a second argument called `gameProcessedEvent` that let's you know whether the action has already been internally processed by the game engine.

When you are using the action normally `gameProcessedEvent` will be `false`, and when you are typing in chat it will be `true`. You can use this to decide when to show your menu or not.

```
UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(Input, gameProcessedEvent)
    -- escape if the user is typing in chat
    if gameProcessedEvent then
        return
    end

    if Input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Keyboard and Input.KeyCode == key then --User pressed key
        if gui.Position == UDim2.new(0.382, 0, 0.229, 0) then --If open
            gui:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.382, 0, 1.229, 0)) --Close UI
        else --Is closed
            gui:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.382, 0, 0.229, 0)) --Open UI
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score -1):

check to see if the user is typing when the m key is pressed (I know you can do that I just don't exactly know how to)